# How do I remove a serialized field correctly in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I save data with a serialized class ,now I want to remove a filed member that no longer necessary ,but the old version has been already serilized as a file,how can I prevent a exception when the new version deserialized from the file?

By the way,this C# is used in Unity3d,mono version

```
 [Serializable]
 public class UserModel {
 // old version 
     Dictionary<string,int> readyToRemoveDict;
 }
 [Serializable]
 public class UserModel {
 //new version 
     //Dictionary<string,int> readyToRemoveDict;
 }
```

//In gameManager ,that's how I saved it

```
 public void SaveData()
 {
     BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
     FileStream file  = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/user.db");

     bf.Serialize(file,userModel);// this is the UserModel
     file.Close();
 }
```

I try add `[OptionalFiled]` but still not an exception

Comment: "I try add [OptionalFiled] but still not an exception" I thought this is what you intended? Not to throw an exception when the field is not set.

Answer (score 0):

You must keep compatibility  between the old and the new code. Then, while you will be make deserialization of new obiect, did not appear an exception.

It is required to leave all properties of the class and this property which are not used set the attribute as the NonSerialized.

When you recive an object UserModel from file, the readyToRemoveDict property will 
have a null value.

Example:

```
[Serializable]
public class UserModel
{
      // New version
      [NonSerialized]
      public Dictionary <string, int> readyToRemoveDict;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot！that‘s very helpful!